# How to extract integers from a string?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int convert_to_minutes(int h, int m) {
    int total_minutes;
    total_minutes = (h * 60) + m;
    return total_minutes;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    //char duration[257];
    //scanf("%s", duration);

    int hours, minutes, total_minutes;
    scanf("%d:%d", &hours, &minutes);
    total_minutes = convert_to_minutes(hours, minutes);
    printf("\n%d\n0", total_minutes);

    return 0;
}
```

How to extract integers from a string?
If a string is passed in like `HH:MM`, how do I scan the first 2 letters of the string and convert to an integer then copy the last 2 letters `MM` and convert to an integer?

**Testcases:**

1) Input: `13:05`, Output: `785`

2) Input: `00:00`, Output: `0`

3) Input: `00:42`, Output: `42`

Comment: `scanf`reads from the standard input. A similar function exists for strings: `sscanf`

Comment: Ok thanks I'll read about fscanf

Comment: I am sorry, I corrected. It is `sscanf` for strings. `fscanf`is for streams (e.g. a file).

Comment: Perfect I'll check out sscanf

Comment: (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS What is that code? Explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int hours=0,minutes=0,total_minutes=0;
    scanf("%d:%d",&hours,&minutes);

    total_minutes=(hours*60)+minutes;

    printf("%d",total_minutes);

    return 0;
    }
```

The input format definitely gonna be HH:MM so you can try using:

```
scanf("%d:%d",&hours,&minutes);
```

So you just need to scanf the integers, rather than store it in string and extract it to integer.
I hope this solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ely for the recommendation to use `sscanf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Function to convert to minutes
int convert_to_minutes(int h, int m) {
    int total_minutes;
    total_minutes = (h * 60) + m;
    return total_minutes; 
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char duration[257];
    scanf("%s", duration);

    int hours, minutes, total_minutes;

    sscanf(duration, "%d:%d", &hours, &minutes);

    total_minutes = convert_to_minutes(hours, minutes);
    printf("\n%d\n", total_minutes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what happens when the user opens a fire hose on your program with a long input string?  Use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to read the input.

Comment: You should also protect `scanf` with `if (scanf("%256s", duration) != 1) return 1;` and check for invalid input with `if (sscanf(duration, "%d:%d", &hours, &minutes) != 2) { handle invalid input }`

Comment: Also, why output a trailing `0` instead of just `printf("%d\n", total_minutes);`?